# Data Factory deployment through Visaul Studio - doesn't list existing Data Factories

Tags: azure, azure-deployment, azure-data-factory

When attempting to deploy changes to an existing Data Factory on Azure from Visual Studio (2015), I am presented with the below screen where the drop down on the 'Use exisiting Data Factory' option is blank. I should be able to see a number of DF's.

I have access to the relevant subscription and right to deploy, however not entirely sure why it doesn't display the existing data factory.

Any idea why?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem. You need some permissions on the Azure subscription, but I've never figured out which ones exactly. I think you need subscription admin or something. Since I wanted to have automated deployments I ended up with a PowerShell script to do the deployment. For a powershell deployment, [this page](https://blog.abatishchev.ru/2017/03/28/how-to-deploy-azure-data-factory-pipeline-and-its-dependencies-using-powershell/) should get you started.